# How to align item labels?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

When I try to answer the a matching question in my assignment, I find that my final PDF of the four answers shown above are not aligned with each other. It seems that the lowercase "b" is taking more space than "a", "c","d".

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem?

[image: A strange formatting pattern in Latex]

Comment: Load `enumitem` package and use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\alpha*.]\item B \item C \end{enumerate}`.

Comment: Hi and welcome, you are doing a lot of stuff by hand, for example manual line breaks and manual spacing. In general, this should be avoided.

Comment: @Johannes_B, Thank you for answering my questions. But how can I avoid  doing those manually, and can you tell me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: @Sigur Do I have to this package every time when I try to type something? I do no  see any other formatting problem without using this package. What is actually happening to my Tex? Also, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Avoiding manual stuff can only be done after reading introductory material and really understanding the pic picture that is LaTeX. You want to have a specific space, but there is an idea behind that. You should give that idea a name and use the name to mrk up the space. Just like you don't manually mark up a section heading, but use `\section`.

Comment: Package `enumitem` can align the labels left, center or right. You  can choose. But that one letter might be taking up more space than another is no big mystery, just compare *A* and *i*. If you want to have letters with the same width for the whole alphabet, you are looking for a monospaced font (typewriter/teletype), like `courier`.

Comment: @David, the default for `enumerate` is to use numbers. If you want other counter, like a. or i., or I. etc... it is good to use that package to help you to format. If you want to use the same format for labels for the whole document, you can pass some option to the package, instead of pass it to every list.

Comment: don't number things by hand using latex and don't use `~\\ ` to force white space (you should never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph) similarly `problem 1` is clearly a heading so should be marked as such (and automatically numbered) not numbered by hand with an explicit  font change.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you very much. I used the enumerate package and solved my problem.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am a beginner of Latex so I am still struggling to understand the basic function and syntax of Latex. That's why my codes look like a mess. Thank you for telling me how I can improve my coding and helping me solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Please always post the code not just an image of code.

You only showed a tiny fragment but it shows that you are missing most of the features of latex to automate numbering, layout and cross references.

Possibly something like the following would be a reasonable markup, then the
layout can be adjusted if needed without changing the markup, which is a major
advantage of a system like latex, but is defeated if you have explicit font changes and spacing commands and manual numbering in the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}% a b c 
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\renewcommand\figurename{Plot}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}% A B C
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Pick one of these:
\begin{enumerate}
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item A
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
something\ldots

In Plot~\ref{zz} which shows\ldots

in Plot~\ref{www} which shows\ldots

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(0,10){\line(1,-1){10}}
\end{picture}
\caption{something\label{zz}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(0,0){\line(1,1){10}}
\end{picture}

\caption{something\label{www}}
\end{figure}

\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would really be better if the problem texts are not italic.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, although I was trying to get the markup half way reasonable before looking at the output. `amsthm` package can be used to specify fonts and other aspects of the `problem` environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is very kind of you read my crappy question and answer the question in such details. I really appreciate your help. I am a beginner so I make mistakes all the time. But thanks to your help, I solved the problem yesterday.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Now I have solved the problem. Thanks for helping me.